# Audio recording in AMR

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am creating a Windwows Phone 7 application which needs that audio from the microphone should be stored in AMR format.

I'm able to catch MemoryStream from microphone, but how can I save that stream with AMR codec?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In reply to my own question for future readers: I solved the audio compression using the cspeex library from http://cspeex.codeplex.com, but I had to modify the code a little just to make it suitable for WP7. It wasn't so hard.